# OM3 optical fiber 850 nm compatibility with 10GBASE-LRM

Tags: cisco, layer1, cable, fiber, interface

I have Cisco equipement with "XENPAK-10GB-LRM" and Optical Fiber Type OM3 wavelength 850 nm. As the LRM interface works at 1310 nm, will it work with this type of Fiber.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only took a few seconds to find this: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/catalyst-6500-series-supervisor-engine-720/product_data_sheet09186a008007cd00.html

It says:

> Cisco XENPAK-10GB-LRM: Supports link lengths 220m on standard
>   FDDI-grade multimode fiber (MMF). To ensure that specifications are
>   met over FDDI-grade, OM1 and OM2 fibers, the transmitter should be
>   coupled through a mode conditioning patch cord. No mode conditioning
>   patch cord is required for applications over OM3. For additional
>   information on mode conditioning patch cord requirements please see:
>   http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/modules/ps5455/product_bulletin_c25-530836.html.

Comment: I agree with you, but what about the XENPAK-10GB-LRM that works at wavelength 1300 nm ?

Comment: That quote is for that exact part. It works on OM3 with no conditioning. It is clear that it should work.

Comment: We run LRM  on OM3 extensively to our campus IDF's, One caveat for LRM over OM3 on shorter runs or runs with little db loss is the foot note in the link that Ron sent. We have run into it many times and use 3-5db attenuators. 
Note: 1. For customers using OM3 fiber type, It is highly recommended to measure the power level before plugging the fiber into the adjacent receiver. When the received power is measured to be above 0.5dBm, a 5-dB attenuator for 1300nm should be used and plugged at the transmitter source of the optical module on each side of the link. LRM's are hot on short runs. fwiw